# Debug in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I try to run the debugger in Visual Studio 2022 with my C# program, it launches the unmodified version without my changes, even when I save them or exit then re-open Visual Studio. What can I do to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Does your program compile without errors? What happens if you delete the bin directory and launch again?

Answer (score 2):

Build → Rebuild Solution

Now go to the Error List tab to check what errors are preventing your solution from building

To prevent this in the future go to Tools → Options → Projects and Solutions → Build And Run and make sure the deployment error option is set to "Do not launch"

[image]